# black login screen after netinstall of debian 7

Tags: debian, debian-wheezy

I installed debian through the net insall cd and selected the debian desktop environment. I am new to debian so I have no idea on what to do. I have googled but the answers I found were for Nvidia realted cards. Mine is an onboard intel card.

Hope someone can help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try something for me -

Log in as root:

```
login: root <Enter>
password: <Password you set during installation> <Enter>
```

Then:

`startx`

Let me know what it returns. Any errors or such?